# onPrepareSubMenu in a custom ActionProvider never called

Tags: android, menuitem, shareactionprovider

Before I ask the question let me give some additional info:

I have a Fragment which adds a `MenuItem` in the `onCreateOptionsMenu`. The added MenuItem also has a custom `ActionProvider` added to it.

The custom `ActionProvider` doesn't use a ActionView but instead prepares a `SubMenu` with certain items to choose from. For this reason I've setup the `ActionProvider` as follows:

- I return `null` in the `onCreateActionView` method
- `hasSubMenu()` returns `true`
- In `onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu Menu)` I first clear the current menu, afterwards add the needed items
- I correctly handle the `onMenuItemClick` in the ActionProvider
- Since I'm using ActionBarSherlock, my ActionProvider extends `com.actionbarsherlock.view.ActionProvider` rather then `android.support.v4.view.ActionProvider` (don't know if it should make any difference, but at this point I don't know what does)

This all goes well on devices with Android versions higher then 3.0. I see the added `MenuItem`, it has the correct `SubMenu` (from the bound `ActionProvider`) and the correct actions take place for each menu option. But with devices running Android versions below 3.0 (I could only test this on a device running 2.3.6) something weird happens; hence the following question.

Google clearly states:

> "onPerformDefaultAction()
>
> The system calls this when the menu item is selected from the action overflow and the action provider should perform a default action for the menu item.
>   However, if your action provider provides a submenu, through the onPrepareSubMenu() callback, then the submenu appears even when the action provider is placed in the action overflow. Thus, onPerformDefaultAction() is never called when there is a submenu."
>
> Taken from: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#CreatingActionProvider

From the excerpt I take it `onPerformDefaultAction()` should NEVER be called in my custom ActionProvider. Yet on devices running Android version 2.3.6 the `onPerformDefaultAction()` DOES get called, which also prevents the `SubMenu` from showing.

My question is; why does the `onPerformDefaultAction()` gets called instead of the `onPrepareSubMenu(SubMenu Menu)`? I need a submenu on devices running Android 2.3.6 as well..

---

**EDIT:**

I managed to fix my problem using the same technique from the `SubMenus.java` from the ActionbarSherlock demo-code. This involves adding a `SubMenu` instead of a custom ActionProvider to the menu in `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`, and attaching `OnMenuItemClickListener` to each MenuItem there.

The workaround is nice and simple. Still, this does not answer my question as to why custom ActionProviders do not work.